# dart url parameters get corrupted

Tags: dart

Given the following simple code

```dart
Uri url = new Uri.http("localhost:8090", "/browseDirectories",{"path":"\log\fastdmo.localhost.log"});

http.get( url).then( (response) {
    print( response.body);
 });
```

I find that the http.get() method does not make the correct call on the web server
As far as I can see the url becomes

`http://localhost:8090/browseDirectories?path=log%0Castdmo.localhost.log`

I know this is because the leading \ of the path parameter gets dropped, but how do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raw string by prefixing the string with r:

```dart
Uri url = new Uri.http("localhost:8090", "/browseDirectories",{"path":r"\log\fastdmo.localhost.log"});
```

which will result in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8090/browseDirectories?path=%5Clog%5Cfastdmo.localhost.log
```

Alternatively, you can use a second backslash to escape the backslash:

```dart
Uri url = new Uri.http("localhost:8090", "/browseDirectories",{"path":"\\log\\fastdmo.localhost.log"});
```